# How to correctly reference .css file from handlebars while making /public/css and /public/img folders static?

Tags: css, handlebars.js

I am having trouble making my handlebars file access my .css file. 
My current folder structure looks like this:

```
root
  public
    css
      base.css (css file)
    img
      ping.png (image file)
```

I am currently making /public/img folder and /public/css folder static using this code:

```
['css', 'img'].forEach(folder => app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/' + folder)));
```

And I am referencing my .css file from handlebars using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

I have tried to use other answers that are on stackoverflow but I don't think the answers work the same way for my project.

Is there any other mistake that I am making here? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. 
Since the .js file where I make /public/css folder and /public/img folder are in the same directory as /public folder is, I should have used `['css', 'img'].forEach(folder => app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/' + folder)));`